# How to send Order broadcast receiver using pending intent android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-broadcastreceiver

Hi i have function like when user hit on notification i have to check my application is in foreground if it so, just close the notification. Otherwise need to open up the application.

I have use concept of ordered broadcast to achieve but i am stuck to call ordered broadcast receiver from pending intent.

Comment: You can only send an ordered broadcast from code. You cannot create a `PendingIntent` that will send an ordered broadcast. Why do you need an ordered broadcast to solve your problem? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

To send an ordered broadcast using a `PendingIntent`, use one of the `send()` methods, for example [this one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#send(int,%20android.app.PendingIntent.OnFinished,%20android.os.Handler)), that takes a `PendingIntent.OnFinished` argument.  This capability is not explicitly documented and only the description of the parametersto [PendingIntent.OnFinished](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.OnFinished.html) gives some hint that ordered broadcasts are supported.

Here is example for sending an ordered broadcast:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.my.package.TEST_ACTION");

PendingIntent.OnFinished listener = new PendingIntent.OnFinished() {
    @Override
    public void onSendFinished(PendingIntent pendingIntent, Intent intent,
                               int resultCode, String resultData, Bundle resultExtras) {
        Log.i("TEST", String.format("onSendFinished(): result=%d action=%s",
                            resultCode, intent.getAction()));
    }
};

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

int initResult = -1;

try {
    pi.send(initResult, listener, null);
} catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I confirmed that this produces an ordered broadcast by defining a number of receivers with this general form, registered in the manifest with different priorities:

```
public class ReceiverA extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("AAAA", String.format("result=%d ordered=%b", getResultCode(), isOrderedBroadcast()));
        setResultCode(1111);
    }
}
```

The `logcat` output confirmed that the receivers were invoked in the expected order, that `isOrderedBroadcast()` is true for each, and the result code set by `setResultCode()` is passed to the next receiver, and finally to the `PendingIntent.OnFinished` callback.

Comment: @David Wasser: Because this answer is at odds with your comment on the question, and you have a longer history with Android than I do, I'd appreciate your review and comments on this.